# On Mavericks, in the Finder in List view, column widths keep changing

Tags: finder, macos, folders, plist

I'm on OS X Mavericks. In Finder, I use the "List" view. In this view, since upgrading to Mavericks, the column widths keep changing. Basically, the `Name` column expands to fill the window up, when you resize a Finder window. But worse of all, they are then fixed at that new width. So for instance, I open a folder, such as `~/Downloads`, then increase the width horizontally to the right. I close this, then open `~/`, which is the original width size. I then open the `~/Downloads` folder, and now the columns are wider than the window.

Is there any way to stop this from happening? Does this only happen to me? I already tried resetting my `com.apple.finder.plist` file, but since Mavericks now caches plist files, the file just gets re-created instantly after deleting it, so that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You can still reset Finder's preferences by running `defaults delete com.apple.Finder;killall Finder;open -a Finder`.

Comment: Okay thanks. That's certainly a bit more complicated than in previous OSes to just delete the file.

Comment: I'm guessing to run this command, I need to use `sudo`? For the `defaults` part, anyway.

Comment: not following your problem exactly, but try holding alt (option) while resizing.  Should do the trick

Comment: I think you are referring to the Columns view? I am referring to the List view.

Comment: How are you opening the folder?

Comment: Normally, I click on the Finder icon in my Dock, then browse to where I want to go.

Comment: in List view when i open the finder the Name column will always resize to fill the entire finder window width for me. Would love to see a fix so i can keep the date mod in the window too for sorting.

Comment: Yep Jim that is the same thing that happens to me. Glad I'm not the only one. I assume that this happens to everyone, but only some people seem to "notice" it. I guess because for novices, it may be hard to pinpoint exactly what is going on, so it becomes hard to explain.

Answer (score 9):

I was so sick of this, so I decided to write a fix once and for all.

You can use the following AppleScript to resize the column widths when you notice the column is too wide. It works by resizing the Finder window really large, then back to it's original size, triggering a fluid layout resize.

```
tell application "Finder"
  tell the front Finder window
    -- get the current bounds of the finder window
    set b to the bounds
    -- create a really wide window
    set the bounds to {item 1 of b, item 2 of b, 3000, item 4 of b}
    -- set window back to its original size
    set the bounds to b
  end tell
end tell
```

This will probably be most useful if bound to a keyboard shortcut, I personally bound it to CMD + E using BetterTouch Tool.

If you're after more detailed information regarding this, you can head over to my blog post about it here: https://christianvarga.com/fix-finder-name-column-width-bug-osx-mavericks/

Comment: Oh thanks for the script Christian !
I had the same "width column" problem, now one click "et voilà"

Comment: This is great!  I have had this problem as well.  Some column-view folders I haven't opened for months, when I do open them, they have the first column so wide that the other columns are not visible at all.  This script fixes them!

Answer (score 1):

He means the column width in list view "name" "date modified" "size" etc

I have the same problem, and it is a major pain when i can't see the size of files because the default width of the column is too small even if i stretch, it will reset as soon as i change folders

Comment: Raise a bug, http://radar.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to fix this.

1. Open a new Finder window.
2. If not all of the columns are visible, drag the lower right corner of the window to the right until they are.
3. Resize the first column to be narrower.
4. Close the window immediately.
5. Open another new Finder window. Is this Finder window too wide?

   - If yes:

     1. drag the lower right corner to the left to make the window the width you want.
     2. close the window immediately.
     3. open a new Finder window again.
   - If no:

     4. you don’t need to do anything else.

This seems to have permanently fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -4):

... or you could use xtrafinder (http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/)

Comment: An edit to show how this software meets the need would turn this into a good answer worth voting up IMO. Especially if it explains how this is a bug or if this behavior is by design from Apple.